# Detecting click on image in ExpandableListView group

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an image inside my group_row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#8fbfff" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_category_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_add_category"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ico_add_item"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to detect when this image was clicked and the id of the Group, and then StartActivityForResult. I was able to do it inside my custom ExpandableListView_Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Category category = arr_categories.get(groupPosition);

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_category, parent, false);
    ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_category_name)).setText(category.getCategory_name());
    ImageView img_add = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_add_category);
    img_add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Add item to category: "+category.getCategory_id(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Declare on intent to use Add/Edit Note activity
            Intent open_add_new_item = new Intent(context, Activity_Add_Edit_Base_Item.class);
            // Pass the currently selected category ID to the Intent
            open_add_new_item.putExtra("CURR_ITEM_CATEGORY", category.getCategory_id());
            // Start the activity
            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(open_add_new_item, Constants.Request_Codes.REQUEST_CODE_CREATE_NEW_ITEM);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

This works just fine. However, If there's a possibility to do so, I'd like to separate this image click detection from the Adapter and do it in my fragment (I think it'll be easier to implement OnActivityResult this way). I tried to do it by setting OnGroupClickListener for my ExpandableListView:

```
master_lv.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {
            final Category c = arr_all_categories.get(groupPosition);
            ImageView img_add = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_add_category);
            img_add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Category c = arr_all_categories.get(groupPosition);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "group position: "+c.getCategory_id(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // Declare on intent to use Add/Edit Note activity
                    Intent open_add_new_item = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity_Add_Edit_Base_Item.class);
                    // Pass the currently selected category ID to the Intent
                    open_add_new_item.putExtra("CURR_ITEM_CATEGORY", c.getCategory_id());
                    // Start the activity
                    startActivityForResult(open_add_new_item, Constants.Request_Codes.REQUEST_CODE_CREATE_NEW_ITEM);

                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

However this didn't work at all: I'm not getting the Toast message and the Intent doesn't fire.

Is it possible to do so? If it is - how? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one you need to do is set `clickable=true` to root layout of the custom cell xml.

After that, what we are going to do is Custom Event Raising. We will use interfaces.

Create a interface class

Example :

`public interface OnImageClickListener {
   public void onImageClicked();
}`

Then create a instance in adapter

`public OnImageClickListener mListener;`

Also set OnClickListener to imageview in getView method of the adapter and add the following line in OnClick method.

`mListener.OnImageClicked();`

Lastly, in Activity;

`mAdapter.mListener = new OnImageClickListener();` 
Magic will happen here :)

or you can implement this interface like

`public MyActivity implements OnItemClickListener` and let the implement methods.

Then you can

`mAdapter.mListener = this;`

Good luck there :)

Comment: Very cool! Thanks! Just passed the Group ID variable to the interface `public void onImageClicked(int group_id);` and after that implementation worked like a charm - got a Toast msg and the Intent fired! Thank you very much! I guess from here OnActivityResult should be implemented as usually, right?

Comment: Great to hear that worked. And Yes you can just keep going like usual implementation of startactivityforresult.  :) please don't forget to mark my answer :)

Comment: Great! Once again, thank you very much for your help! Much appreciated! :)